# Filling BSF186 and BSF186a for first landing as a Canadian PR under express entry

Tags: immigration, canada, resident-permit, express-entry

1. Should I carry filled BSF186 and BSF186a forms myself? Is it mandatory? or can I just carry my own excel list with details?
2. Can BSF186 alone be used for both "Goods accompanying" and "Goods to follow" (on separate sheets)? If so, what is BSF186a for? and how to differentiate between the "goods accompanying" BSF186 form and the "Goods to follow" form since they are both same format and there is no option to differentiate both on the form itself? I mean, should I hand-write "goods accompanying" and "goods to follow" on top of each to differentiate?
3. What if I do not have any "goods to follow"? I am travelling solo with no dependents and my possessions are meager, so I could manage to carry all of them with me. I am not moving anything like furniture, car or kitchen appliances or jewelry.

Comment: I think they give the forms to fill out. Not sure what has changed since I landed.

Comment: @DipenShah, if you don't mind, when did you land? If it was fairly recent and if I am not expected to carry any pre-filled forms, then I'd be happy

Comment: Almost 3 years back. And I did a flagpole landing.